# Send emails from Salesforce with attachments to create tasks in Outlook?

Tags: apex, email, tasks, outlook

One of the requirements for the project is to automatically send mails with events/tasks from Salesforce whenever an event/task is created/edited/deleted.

I was able to send events and updates, but now I'm sort of stuck with tasks.

When I send an `.ics` file to outlook, it appears as an attachment and I can click on it and then click on a button to add it to calendar. However, the spinner shows and after a while it just becomes a fat red cross:

[image]
[image]

I have also found, that Outlook does not support VTODO items([MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624464%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)), which are actually tasks that I need.

So the question is:

**How can I(or is it even possible?) send emails from Salesforce with attachments to create tasks in Outlook?**

**EDIT**

Some more explanation as asked by [Adrian Larson](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2995/adrian-larson) in his comment.

For events I just created an apex method which takes a few parameters, build a string and returns blob value of this string which I then attach to the body. Here's a quick example:

```
public static Blob generateBody(String method, String summary /*more parameters*/) {
    String bodyString = '';
    bodyString += 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n';
    // Many more lines
    return Blob.valueOf(bodyString);
}
```

And the resulting `.ics` attachment is:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20170105T114349Z
DTEND:20170105T144349Z
DTSTAMP:20170105T114349Z
ORGANIZER;CN=me:MAILTO:my_email_here
UID:testEvent20
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=
 TRUE;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:my_email_here
CREATED:20170102T114349Z
DESCRIPTION:this is just a test
LAST-MODIFIED:20170102T114349Z
LOCATION:TBD
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:summary
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

and this works perfectly for events. However, when I tried to create a task(VTODO), it would not open in Outlook(see screenshots at the top). The body of a task is:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTODO
ORGANIZER:Mailto:my_email_here
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:Mailto:my_email_here
DTSTART:20170107T143000Z
DUE:20170108T143000Z
PRIORITY:1
SUMMARY:Test task
UID:50m3_v3ry_un1qu3_1d-1397geohsulffo3suv3894g8030afhs4iog
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20170104T141839Z
STATUS:Needs Action
END:VTODO
END:VCALENDAR
```

When I downloaded this attachment and double clicked it, it opened Reminders app and created a reminder(task) there. Yes, I'm using Mac.

Comment: have you tried the Success forum?

Comment: It might also be easier to help if you share more information about the attachments you are sending? How are you building them? What do they look like?

Comment: @AdrianLarson done

Comment: @cropredy nope. I did find some similar questions there though, but they did not really help

Comment: Should that semicolon after `ATTENDEE` be a colon instead? That's the only thing that seems amiss, though I haven't worked with this kind of attachment before.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I don't think so. There is a colon after `RSVP=TRUE` and this is a part of that `ATTENDEE` parameter. Also, it does work as expected if I just double click this file